# C++ preprocessor executing both #ifdef and #ifndef

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

So I'm currently working on something that uses OpenCL. The OpenCL spec provides the users with a directive which must be included before the inclusion of the header (cl.h)

`#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 110`

Which basically defines the version they want to use. Suppose I'm making a library and I want my users to define this instead of me defining this inside my files. What I did was.

```
-----main.cpp---
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 110
#include "library.h"
-------x---------

----library.h-----
#ifdef CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION
#pragma message("def")
#endif

#ifndef CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION
#pragma message("ndef")
#endif
.... include other headers.
--------x---------
```

And the compiler prints both `def` and `ndef` messages. And the OpenCL library also throws a warning that it's undefined. I thought that the library header would get substituted into main and it'd only print the `def` message. Is there anything I understood wrong?

I'm particularly confused as to where does the preprocessor start? If it starts from `main.cpp` and goes from top to down, then it surely has defined the macro. After that it sees the library inclusion, then it should only print the `def` message but it prints both.

This leds me to believe the preprocessor does scan the header file before including it in main? Dunno the reason why. Also I have assured that the library header isn't included elsewhere.

One interesting thing I noticed was, if i did this

```
-----helper.h---
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 110    
-------x---------

----library.h-----
#include helper.h    
#ifdef CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION
#pragma message("def")
#endif

#ifndef CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION
#pragma message("ndef")
#endif
.... include other headers.
--------x---------
```

It prints the `def` message "twice". If anybody can explain all this I'd be grateful.

EDIT:- The files I'm compiling are `main.cpp` `library.h` and `library.cpp` 
`Library.cpp` includes `library.h` from the start as usual. Maybe this other cpp is causing the problem?

Comment: maybe you include `library.h` twice and have no include guards ? Since the code you provide is partial it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Include guards are present, my IDE does this automatically (Code blocks)

Comment: How many source files are you compiling? Just main.cpp?

Comment: Also add `#endif`s.

Comment: @gudok - totally forgot, I have them added in my files though :s

Comment: @Olivier - Library.h, Library.cpp and main. I think that's critical info I forgot to add. Should add it.

Comment: So my guess is that some pragma messages are generated while compiling main.cpp, some other are generated while compiling Library.cpp. But you think they are generated while compiling a single source, and it confuses you (when you compile Library, you probably have `CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION` not defined).

Comment: Is it that you are using #pragma once and you are not on a Windows environment ? 
Try using 
#ifndef XXXX_h
#define XXXX_h
#endif

Comment: @Olivier - So is there any other way to get rid of this problem and still give my users the option to define the version they want to use?

Comment: @Mohd - I'm on windows, and no im using just #pragma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C/C++ programs, the compiler handles each .c and .cpp file separately.

The compilers build each source file (NOT the header files, only .c and .cpp files) independently from each other (this source files are called `compilation unit`).

Thus, when your main.cpp is built, the compiler finds the `#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 110` you have added on top of the main.cpp file, emiting the `def`message.

But when the compiler builds the `library.cpp` file, it does not find the version define, so it emits the `ndef` message.

So, following this explanation, it is completely normal that in your last case, when you add the define to the .h file, the compiler emits the `def` message twice, once for the main.cpp file and once for the library.cpp file.

---

Now, the problem is where should you add the define, in order to have the program built consistently, with the same version for all the .cpp files.

Usually, all the IDEs have some configuration page where you can add global defines, for all the project, which are "inserted" into all the compilation units before everything else. So when the IDE calls the compiler, it passes the same defines to all the compilation units. You should add this kind of defines in this page.

In your IDE (I am using Code::Blocks, v 17.12), you can find this page in the menu: `Project / Build Options`

For each type (Debug or Release), you have to go to the tab `Compiler Settings`, and there to the sub tab `#defines`. There you can add global defines, which can be different if you are building in Debug or in Release mode (of course, if you set the same in both modes, they would be the same).

Once you have added your define here, please, remove it from the `main.cpp`, `library.h` and any other place where you may have added it, in order to avoid duplicities.

---

From the comments about portability:

You have several options:

- Always use Code::Blocks: this would be the easiest way, since you can pass the Code::Blocks project along with the source files, and everything would be already setup.
- Use `cmake`, which is a script build system, where you can set defines and so in the same way as using an IDE. `cmake` is much widely used than Code::Blocks, so maybe it is a better option.
- Add a new `options.h` header file, where you set all the `defines`, and include it to all your .c/.cpp. This setup has the additional benefit that for different systems, changing only the `options.h` file the build can be completely different. This is a manually setup of what the IDE is doing. It has the advantage that does not rely on external tools, but the disadvantage that you have to remember to add it in all the new .cpp files added to the project.

My recommendation is go with `cmake`, just as the others have said.

Comment: Hmm, is this the only way to do this? What if we suppose someone's using an IDE that doesn't have this global macro or maybe he isn't using an IDE at all. C++ people usually like to do the compiling from command line I think.

Comment: @wandering-warrior: Usually developers use some build script like make or build system like cmake. There you can set this variables. With cmake you can generate a CodeBlocks project

Comment: Oh, ok, then this means the proper way is that I should mention it in my doc that people need to set this macro either in the global macro or in the scripts you defined?

Comment: If you want portability, you should use cmake to configure your project and generate a CodeBlocks project from cmake. Then you don't need to mention it in your docs. Cmake will set the defines independent of ide.

Comment: @wandering-warrior I have added the portability options to the answer

Answer (score 1):

**Prefer using #ifndef XXXX_h #define XXXX_h #endif over #pragma once**

If your `#include` search path is sufficiently complicated, the compiler may be unable to tell the difference between two headers with the same basename `(e.g. a/foo.h and b/foo.h)`, so a `#pragma once` in one of them will suppress both. It may also be unable to tell that two different relative includes `(e.g. #include "foo.h" and #include "../a/foo.h"` refer to the same file, so `#pragma` once will fail to suppress a redundant include when it should have.

This also affects the compiler's ability to avoid rereading files with `#ifndef` guards, but that is just an optimization. With `#ifndef` guards, the compiler can safely read any file it isn't sure it has seen already; if it's wrong, it just has to do some extra work. As long as no two headers define the same guard macro, the code will compile as expected. And if two headers do define the same guard macro, the programmer can go in and change one of them.

`#pragma` once has no such safety net -- if the compiler is wrong about the identity of a header file, either way, the program will fail to compile. If you hit this bug, your only options are to stop using `#pragma` once, or to rename one of the headers. The names of headers are part of your API contract, so renaming is probably not an option.

(The short version of why this is problematic to use `#pragma` is that neither the Unix nor the Windows filesystem API offer any mechanism that guarantees to tell you whether two absolute pathnames refer to the same file.)

Comment: *"neither the Unix nor the Windows filesystem API offer any mechanism that guarantees to tell you whether two absolute pathnames refer to the same file"* don't you mean *relative* pathnames?

Comment: I mean when the relative pathnames are resolved to absolute path name or absolute pathnames itself.